# How to analyse a data set both grouped by and ungrouped in one analysis using dplyr

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

This is my first stackoverflow question.

I'm trying to use dplyr to process and output a summary of data grouped by a categorical variable (inj_length_cat3) in my dataset. Actually, I generate this variable (from inj_length) on the fly using mutate(). I also want to output the same summary of the data *without* grouping. The only way I figured out how to do that is to do the analysis twice over, once with, once without grouping, and then combine the outputs. Ugh.

I'm sure there is a more elegant solution than this and it bugs me. I wonder if anyone would be able to help.

Thanks!

```
library(dplyr)
df<-data.frame(year=sample(c(2005,2006),20,replace=T),inj_length=sample(1:10,20,replace=T),hiv_status=sample(0:1,20,replace=T))

tmp <- df  %>% 
  mutate(inj_length_cat3 = cut(inj_length, breaks=c(0,3,100), labels = c('<3 years','>3 years')))%>%
  group_by(year,inj_length_cat3)%>%
  summarise(
    r=sum(hiv_status,na.rm=T),
    n=length(hiv_status),
    p=prop.test(r,n)$estimate,
    cilow=prop.test(r,n)$conf.int[1],
    cihigh=prop.test(r,n)$conf.int[2]
  ) %>% 
  filter(inj_length_cat3%in%c('<3 years','>3 years'))

tmp_all <- df  %>% 
  group_by(year)%>%
  summarise(
    r=sum(hiv_status,na.rm=T),
    n=length(hiv_status),
    p=prop.test(r,n)$estimate,
    cilow=prop.test(r,n)$conf.int[1],
    cihigh=prop.test(r,n)$conf.int[2]
  )

tmp_all$inj_length_cat3=as.factor('All')
tmp<-merge(tmp_all,tmp,all=T)
```

Comment: Here's some guidance on asking a good question here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask The key point is to make a [mcve]

Comment: edited with minimal example data frame and better title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you consider this more elegant, but you can get a solution to work if you first create a dataframe that has all your data twice: once so that you can get the subgroups and once to get the overall summary:

```
df1 <- rbind(df,df)
df1$inj_length_cat3 <- cut(df$inj_length, breaks=c(0,3,100,Inf),
                           labels = c('<3 years','>3 years','All'))
df1$inj_length_cat3[-(1:nrow(df))] <- "All"
```

Now you just need to run your first analysis without `mutate()`:

```
tmp <- df1  %>% 
  group_by(year,inj_length_cat3)%>%
  summarise(
    r=sum(hiv_status,na.rm=T),
    n=length(hiv_status),
    p=prop.test(r,n)$estimate,
    cilow=prop.test(r,n)$conf.int[1],
    cihigh=prop.test(r,n)$conf.int[2]
  ) %>% 
  filter(inj_length_cat3%in%c('<3 years','>3 years','All'))
```

Comment: Great,  If this answer worked for you, you can mark the check mark and up vote (the up arrow).

Comment: I did - apparently I need more reputation points!

It would be nicer if you can do the whole thing without having to duplicate the data (which slows the analysis down esp if the dataset is large).