# Getting summary by group and overall using tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, mean, summarize

I am trying to find a way to get summary stats such as means by group and overall in one step using `dplyr`

```
#Data set-up
sex <- sample(c("M", "F"), size=100, replace=TRUE)
age <- rnorm(n=100, mean=20 + 4*(sex=="F"), sd=0.1)
dsn <- data.frame(sex, age)


library("tidyverse")

#Using dplyr to get means by group and overall
mean_by_sex <- dsn %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% 
  summarise(mean_age = mean(age))

mean_all <- dsn %>% 
  summarise(mean_age = mean(age)) %>% 
  add_column(sex = "All")

#combining the results by groups and overall
final_result <- rbind(mean_by_sex, mean_all)
final_result  
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   sex   mean_age
#>   <fct>    <dbl>
#> 1 F         24.0
#> 2 M         20.0
#> 3 All       21.9
#This is the table I want but I wonder if is the only way to do this
```

Is there a way this in shorter step using `group_by_at` or `group_by_all` or a similar functions using tidyverse and `dplyr`
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164350/dplyr-summarize-with-subtotals (which doesn't really have a better answer than what you are using) or another alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045447/how-to-analyse-a-data-set-both-grouped-by-and-ungrouped-in-one-analysis-using-dp

Comment: The https://cran.r-project.org/package=tables package can do that in one line: `library(tables); tabular(sex + 1 ~ age * mean, dsn)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could perhaps be:

```
dsn %>%
 group_by(sex) %>%
 summarise(mean_age = mean(age)) %>%
 add_row(sex = "ALL", mean_age = mean(dsn$age))

  sex   mean_age
  <fct>    <dbl>
1 F         24.0
2 M         20.0
3 ALL       21.9
```

Answer (score 2):

A little switching around can do it, too.

```
final_result <- dsn %>% 
  add_row(sex = "All", age = mean(age)) %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% 
  summarise(mean_age = mean(age))
```

Comment: We posted almost the same thing at the same :) However, there is a substantial difference: your solution won't work if age is not in the global environment.

Comment: Thank you @vanao veneri. I slightly modified the code and it worked

Answer (score 0):

These answers are great if you have one variable to summarize by. What about two? I want to summarize across one but leave the other as is. The above solutions do not work in this case because the data frame still needs to be grouped.

```
#Data set up 
set.seed(3243242)
dsn <- tibble(
  obese = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size=100, replace = TRUE),
  sex = sample(c("M", "F"), size=100, replace=TRUE),
                  age = rnorm(n=100, mean=20 + 4*(sex=="F"), sd=0.1)
                    )
library("tidyverse")
```

I restated the original problem using 2 group_by variables.

```
#Extend to 2 group_by variables?
df1 <- dsn %>%
  group_by(sex, obese) %>% 
  summarise(mean_age = mean(age)) %>%
  ungroup() 

#Also across sex
df2 <- dsn %>%
  group_by(obese) %>% 
  summarise(mean_age = mean(age)) %>%
  ungroup() 

#Final_result:
bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

Way to do this in one step? You can add `mean` with `add_row()` but not with a grouped df. Another option is to create a function that does all the things on the group dataset. If there are other things you want to do, say sort or create new variables, you can do it in the function. Then, you can apply the function to each grouped dataset. After combining via `dplyr::bind_rows()`, you can change the missing group variable to all via `tidyr::replace_na()`.

```
  #'@param df_group A grouped tibble
find_summary <- function(df_group){
  df_group %>% 
summarize(mean_age = mean(age))  #add other dplyr verbs here as needed like arrange or mutate
}

bind_rows(
    find_summary(group_by(dsn, sex, obese)),
    find_summary(group_by(dsn, obese))
    ) %>%
     replace_na(list(sex = "all"))
```

```
sex   obese mean_age
  <chr> <lgl>    <dbl>
1 F     FALSE     24.0
2 F     TRUE      24.0
3 M     FALSE     20.0
4 M     TRUE      20.0
5 all   FALSE     21.7
6 all   TRUE      22.3
```

You can extend the idea if you want a summary of all variables, by one variable, and by two variables.

```
bind_rows(
    find_summary(group_by(dsn, sex, obese)),
    find_summary(group_by(dsn, obese)),
    find_summary(dsn)
    ) %>%
     replace_na(list(sex = "all", obese = "all"))
```

```
  sex   obese mean_age
  <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
1 F     FALSE     24.0
2 F     TRUE      24.0
3 M     FALSE     20.0
4 M     TRUE      20.0
5 all   FALSE     21.7
6 all   TRUE      22.3
7 all   all       22.0
```