# Using Jupyter Lab -Rh ow can I find how many rows of data are recorded for each year on record?

Tags: r, jupyter-lab

Very new to R using Jupyter. When looking at a dataset how can I find how many rows of data are recorded for each year on record? Then how do I find mean, in and max wage for each of those years on record?

Comment: Maybe start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60437783/getting-summary-by-group-and-overall-using-tidyverse

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting summary by group and overall using tidyverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60437783/getting-summary-by-group-and-overall-using-tidyverse)